Filter Data based on the country matrix of the user
I want to filter the data based on the country matrix of the recruiter (user) rather than the logged-in user's ID. The query should fetch the data based on the country matrix of the recruiter associated with the candidates.
But I'm getting the same result for all users. Please help me  to solve this.
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(DATE_SUB(candidate_joborder_status_history.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) - DAYOFWEEK(DATE_SUB(candidate_joborder_status_history.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) + 1 + 1)) as unixdate,
SUM(IF(candidate_joborder_status_history.status_to = 400, 1, 0)) AS submitted, 
SUM(IF(candidate_joborder_status_history.status_to = 500, 1, 0)) AS interviewing, 
SUM(IF(candidate_joborder_status_history.status_to = 800, 1, 0)) AS placed 
FROM candidate_joborder_status_history 
INNER JOIN candidate c ON candidate_joborder_status_history.candidate_id = c.candidate_id 
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.user_id =c.owner 
WHERE candidate_joborder_status_history.site_id = 1 AND FIND_IN_SET(c.country_id, u.country_matrix) > 0 AND u.user_id = c.owner
GROUP BY unixdate 
ORDER BY unixdate DESC LIMIT 20


Please clarify by publishing sample data and expected outcome as text

We need a [mre]

If you want to "LEFT JOIN user u", but you are putting conditions in the WHERE clause that reference the "user" table, you are defeating the purpose of the "LEFT JOIN" and you end-up with an "INNER" one: if you want a LEFT JOIN all conditions should be in the ON part.
Furthermore the condition in the WHERE clause is the same as the one in the JOIN... you should also be sure that the FIND_IN_SET is NULL safe regarding the second parameter if your intent is actually to do a LEFT JOIN.
